# Cannot cast from Byte to byte[] java

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to convert byte array into image in android. 
I have a `ArrayList<Byte> arrays;` that contains all byte arrays that I want to convert. 
Now at

```
byt = (byte[]) arrays.get(0);
```

its giving me `Cannot cast from Byte to byte[] java` exception.

```
        byte[] byt;
        byt = new byte[4096];
        byt = (byte[]) arrays.get(0) ;
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = null;
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byt);

        try {
            bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
            SaveImages();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What type of value does an `ArrayList<Byte>` contains?

Comment: i want to transfer images from my wcf ksoap2 service to android. so i have converted images to byte array and passed to android. here ArrayList<Byte> contains all that byte arrays. here i want to convert byte array to image

Comment: byte[] byt = new byte[arrays.size()];
arrays.toArray(byt);

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList doesn't contain Byte[] or byte[] values, however the list itself can be converted to a byte array as it contains individual byte values

```
        byte[] bytes = new byte[array.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            bytes[i] = array.get(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ByteArrayOutputStream instead of an arraylist, its better. Then you use ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().

Comment: The user is getting an arraylist as input if I understand correctly. This fix is liekly untenable in practice.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Byte> arrays;` does not contain a list of `Byte[]'. It is a single list of boxed Byte objects.

You will need to do a conversion by hand:

```
 byte[] byteArray = new byte[arrays.size()];

 for (int i=0;i<byteArray.length;i++) {
    byteArray[i] = arrays.get(i);
 }
```

The loop will unbox the Byte to a byte for you as it is placed into the array.

Comment: array.length in the for-loop declaration doesn't compile, it needs to be arrays.length() or byteArray.length.

Comment: The OP also indicated that he has an ArrayList of arrays, so your solution should reflect that, I think.

Comment: The OP also indicated that it is a ArrayList<Byte>

Comment: @arne.jans Thanks, I renamed the byteArray but forgot to rename it in the loop. The OP may have said in his post ArrayList of arrays but that's not what the type he said in his code is so I think it's more likely he's misunderstood that than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misusing the `ImageIO` API (correct me if I misunderstood):

You can use `ImageIO.read` with 3 different inputs:

- URL
- File
- InputStream

If you have a file to load - just pass it like so:

```
bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(new File("someFile.jpg"));
```

Or like this if it is within your application:

```
bImageFromConvert =
   ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassloader().getResourceAsStream("com/myapp/images/someFile.jpg"));
```

If you are getting the data as bytes from an outside source - try using a `byte[]` instead of `List<Byte>` which I assume you are using as it is more fitting to the problem you are trying to solve.

Also, note that you allocated only 4K for the image - and this might not be enough for loading your image - which (should) cause `ImageIO.read` to fail.

I'm not adding anything about using a URL - but I assume it is obvious.

If this does not answer your question please add more relevant inputs.

Comment: i want to transfer images from my wcf ksoap2 service to android. so i have converted images to byte array and passed to android. here ArrayList<Byte> contains all that byte arrays. here i want to convert byte array to image

Comment: So you read a byte[] from some service and then you convert it into an ArrayList<Byte> and then you want to convert it back to be byte[]?

Comment: If I understand correctly - you get the image from the SOAP API as a String, probably Base64 encoded - am I right? If so, you can convert the Base64 Encoded string into a byte[] and just go with that

Comment: i filled ArrayList<Byte> from my service, it contains converted images that are in byte array form. now i want to convert them back to images

Comment: If you have no alternative other than getting an `ArrayList<Byte>` follow TimB's answer to convert it into a `byte[]` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21113724/357360

Comment: will you please help regarding passing images from wcf ksoap2 to android. i have to transfer 10-15 images at a time. now i have a new problem, my service is responding correctly but my ArrayList<Byte> is not filling. will you please help?

Comment: Please post a new question as this is off-topic

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115575/trouble-in-receiveing-byte-from-wcf-ksoap2-to-android

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to get an image from soap service to your android device.

I suggest to use the following method,

Read the SOAP object property as a String.

```
String mPhoto;

 if (soapObject.hasProperty(PHOTO)) {
        Object obj = soapObject.getProperty(PHOTO);
        if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(SoapPrimitive.class)) {
            SoapPrimitive j = (SoapPrimitive) obj;
            mPhoto = j.toString();
        } else if (obj != null && obj instanceof String) {
            mPhoto = obj.toString();
        } else {
            mPhoto = null;
        }
    }
```

Then convert that String to byte[]

```
public byte[] getPhoto() {
    if (mPhoto != null) {
           // org.kobjects.base64.Base64;
        return Base64.decode(mPhoto);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Decoding is important to reconstruct the same byte[] sent from the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't use another solution with Byte[] instead.
Then you could use toPrimitive method from ArrayUtils class from Apache Lang library.
Or use this bellow code:

```
public static byte[] toPrimitive(final Byte[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (array.length == 0) {
            return EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY;
        }
        final byte[] result = new byte[array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            result[i] = array[i].byteValue();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your `ArrayList<Byte>` as `ArrayList<byte[]> arrays;`.

Your current declaration, as it is, does not store a list of byte arrays, but a list of `Byte` *objects, not arrays*. Even if your arrays were declared as `ArrayList<Byte[]> arrays;`, you cannot cast a `Byte[]` array to a `byte[]` array. Java does not support directly casting [primitive data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and their [wrapper types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html), nor their array types.

Primitives and their wrapper types are *boxed* or *un-boxed*. The compiler silently replaces declarations such as `Integer myInt = 0;` with `Integer myInt = Integer.valueOf(0);`,  and `int myInt = myWrappedInt;` with `int myInt = myWrappedInt.intValue();` because of the [auto-(un)boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) feature introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs on line 3

```
        byt = (byte[]) arrays.get(0) ;
```

arrays.get(0) returns a Byte which you then try to cast to a byte[]

Comment: It returns a `Byte`, not a `byte`, and this is pretty much just what OP says in the question.

Comment: @Keppil thx for the correction. Still the cause of the Exception is the cast.

Comment: Yes, that is fairly clearly stated in the exception itself. OP is asking how to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

If you tried to put byte-arrays into the ArrayList arrays, then you should correct its declaration to:

```
ArrayList<Byte[]> arrays = new ArrayList<Byte[]>();
```

and fill it with your data.

Comment: The first example isn't even correct Java, and what you are trying to do isn't possible with primitive arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`ArrayList.toArray(T[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T[]%29) method, like so:

```
Byte[] byteArray = new Byte[arrays.size()];
ArrayList.toArray(byteArray);
```

This method uses `System.arrayCopy`, a native method. It is a lot faster than iterating through your whole ArrayList.

Comment: This code even would not compile.