# trouble in receiveing byte [] from wcf ksoap2 to android

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf

I am trying to send images from wcf ksoap2 to android. At wcf side I have converted all images into byte array and stored them in an ArrayList. At android side I trying fill the `ArrayList<Byte> arrays;`  but its not filling, it remains empty. 
Here is my code

wcf:

```
        List<byte[]> list;
        public List<byte[]> loadImages()
        {
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\abc");
            arr1 = new ArrayList();
            foreach (FileInfo fi in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                arr1.Add(fi.FullName);



            list = new List<byte[]>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Count; i++)
            {
                img = Image.FromFile(arr1[i].ToString());
                ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                list.Add(ms.ToArray());
                //                objbyte = (byte[])ms.ToArray();
            }

            return list;
        }
```

android:

```
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelop;
            soapEnvelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelop.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
            HttpTransportSE htps = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            htps.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);
            response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelop.getResponse();    
            ar = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

            arrays = new ArrayList<Byte>();

            if (response != null) {

                if (response.getPropertyCount() > 0) {                  

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                        arrays.add( (Byte) response.getProperty(i)); 
                    }
                }
            }
```

for loop executes properly but `arrays` remains empty

I want to send 10-15 images at a time. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the purpose of `ar = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];`

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see the value of `(Byte) response.getProperty(i)` ?

Comment: ar is String[] ar;. I used it before but that wasn't helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelop;
            soapEnvelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelop.dotNet = true;
            soapEnvelop.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
            HttpTransportSE htps = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            htps.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelop);
            response = (SoapObject) soapEnvelop.getResponse();    
            ar = new String[response.getPropertyCount()];

            arrays = new ArrayList<Byte>();

            if (response != null) {

                if (response.getPropertyCount() > 0) {                  

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

                        arrays.add( (Byte) response.getProperty(i)); 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting the data as a `Byte`, however you have a `Byte[]`

Comment: @yakhtarali `arrays = new ArrayList<Byte>();` should be `arrays = new ArrayList<Byte[]>();` for a start.

Comment: If it was a Casting issue there should have been an Exception on Android's end